# Problem with "drupal_add_js": Conflicts ShareBar module with IMCE popup

Tags: 7, files

I have installed ShareBar module (https://www.drupal.org/project/sharebar) at my drupal 7 site. Unfortunately it caused that on IMCE popup (when we can upload images) doesn't appear buttons for files management e.g. upload file.

The code snippet from **sharebar.module**:

```
if (variable_get('sharebar_bar_horizontal', TRUE)) {
  $hori = 'TRUE';
}
else {
  $hori = 'FALSE';
}
$width = variable_get('sharebar_bar_width', 1000);
$swidth = variable_get('sharebar_bar_swidth', 75);
$position = variable_get('sharebar_bar_position', 'left');
$leftoffset = variable_get('sharebar_bar_leftoffset', 10);
$rightoffset = variable_get('sharebar_bar_rightoffset', 10);
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'sharebar') . '/js/sharebar.js');
drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function($) { $(\'.sharebar\').sharebar({horizontal:\'' . $hori . '\',swidth:\'' . $swidth . '\',minwidth:' . $width . ',position:\'' . $position . '\',leftOffset:' . $leftoffset . ',rightOffset:' . $rightoffset . '}); });', 'inline');
```

I noticed that this issue is due the last line:

```
drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function($) { $(\'.sharebar\').sharebar({horizontal:\'' . $hori . '\',swidth:\'' . $swidth . '\',minwidth:' . $width . ',position:\'' . $position . '\',leftOffset:' . $leftoffset . ',rightOffset:' . $rightoffset . '}); });', 'inline');
```

My guess is that this may be caused by a jQuery libriaries conflict, but I have no idea what can I do more with this line. I have tried:

- put this in new file *.js
- add line in `(function($) { /* ... */ })(jQuery);`
- install JQuery multi module: https://www.drupal.org/project/jqmulti

Can you assist me? What can I do more?

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no errors in the console related to JQuery library and these modules.

Comment: But are there errors in the console? If there are any JavaScript errors it would stop further execution

Comment: What do you mean by "in the console"? I don't have any error at the site and report.

Comment: If you are using Chrome in the Developer Tools, other browsers have similar options, etc. http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers

Comment: Thank you, I have found problem in the console and than I have red about this .js error at: https://www.drupal.org/node/2076219